# What happens when people run out of questions to ask?

Tags: discussion

What will happen when people can't ask anymore questions? The website sky-rocketed with tons of questions within 6 months. What happens when the questions people ask are so similar to other old questions that they will be constantly deleted? I am aware that new games will appear but not everyone plays every single new game.

Comment: I don't understand your point. You acknowledge that new games will continuously generate new questions, so I'm not sure why you think there will some sort of question shortage. Unless you are referring to individuals running out of questions, which is simply not a problematic situation. There is no expectation that people will ask questions continuously. Also, this site has been around for 3 years, not 6 months.

Comment: I am aware the site has been here for 3 years There was however a 10000 question boom with in the last 6 months.

Comment: Perhaps, but you didn't answer any of the actual questions in my comment. What is your problem/point?

Comment: My point is that people will always play the same games. Minecraft for example will be around for a while. If every question is possibly asked how will newcomers react to a site that offers them no way of "making a name" for themselves.

Comment: This site is not *about* "making a name for yourself". It is about providing knowledge to the internet, and providing an answer to every possible question about every game ever would achieve that admirably. However, even with the 30,000 questions we have now, we have barely begun to scratch the surface of those depths, and as you point out, there *will* always be new games to ask about.

Comment: Ok you have a good point.

Comment: Plus, as long as Minecraft continues to be updated with new features and content - there will be new minecraft questions to answer, and some old ones to re-answer with more up-to-date answers.

Comment: Stackoverflow hasn't run out of questions yet, and C and C++ sure haven't changed much over the years!

Comment: People keep making new games.  Therefore, we will always keep asking new questions.

Comment: It is our duty.

Comment: If people on this site have run out of questions then Arqade has reached it's ultimate goal. We might actually ascent into better beings. Too bad that's never gonna happen since stupid questions do not exist :D.

Comment: @SaintWacko You said duty

Comment: @MennoGouw Have you *seen* some of the closed/deleted questions here?

Comment: "My point is that people will always play the same games".. uhuh.. maybe *you* are one of those people. Please don't count me in.

Answer (score 4):

Sure enough, we thrive during times of big releases but the same can be said about many stackexchange sites.

However, the problem of "running out of questions" is never going to be a problem. While we get large bursts of traffic and new questions during periods that new games are getting released, we also have a steady stream of questions and answers about older games.

Regardless to all of this, the information on the site remains relevant for anybody playing any game that we have a question/answer for.

Comment: And there's always replaying old favorites, and asking questions about those.